# Menu / div of year and months of blog posts?

Tags: menus, blog

I want a menu or a dive with this content where you can click on and see the blog posts from the selected date

that is like this

```
BLOG

 -2014

   -january

   -february

   -march

   -....

 -2013
```

the months and years should be added automatically.

Is there something that can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`wp_get_archives`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) function will generate a list of links to date archives.